# Need to call a webservice through Proxy in Android App

Tags: java, android, web-services, proxy

I need to consume a GET web service, which usually returns 403 as it is behind captcha service.
That is, when opening the address in the browser it returns a google captcha page, once it's validated, I can view the JSON response. And the service works fine after that. The captcha pops back when it's not called for some time, say 1 hour.
There is no captcha when the address is opened using US proxy.

I need help for connecting the service using the proxy via code or should I call a webview on it, validate the captcha and then return back the result. Any code samples for both the solutions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can configure proxy in your testing device.

Comment: How to use it in production